# Creating aliases in .bash_profile that run a shell script

Tags: shell, bash

So I have a script called spotlyrics.sh that I want to be able to run using the command "lyrics" in the terminal.

I have opened up my .bash_profile and am wondering how I can create the alis which 1) finds the script and then 2) executes it

The file is inside a folder called `bash` at the following path

```
/Users/username/Documents/bash
```

What I have so far (inside my bash profile), which doesn't work because I guess it's not "executing" the script.

```
alias spotlyrics=“/Users/username/Documents/bash/spotlyrics.sh“
```

I get the following error when running "spotlyrics" in the terminal:

```
-bash: “/Users/username/Documents/bash/spotlyrics.sh“: No such file or directory
```

Would love some help, thanks!

Comment: Try: `alias spotlyrics='/Users/username/Documents/bash/spotlyrics.sh'`

Comment: same issue . "no such file or directory"

Comment: @user2656127: Please verify that your path is correct by checking the output of `ls '/Users/username/Documents/bash/spotlyrics.sh'`.

Comment: ok what does `ls -l /Users/username/Documents/bash/spotlyrics.sh` show?

Comment: Yes that succssfully shows the correct path

Comment: and what happens when you enter `/Users/username/Documents/bash/spotlyrics.sh` on command line?

Comment: Does the script run OK when invoked directly? What does the shebang line inside the `.sh` file say?

Comment: The script works :) Thanks for that - obviously needed to just switch up the alias :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've been editing your `.bash_profile` with something that is not a proper text editor. The quotation marks are not ASCII, and therefore not actually quotation marks as far as the shell is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of beating around the bush with aliasing a script to a name it mostly already has, why not put the script in a directory in PATH and let it be its own command?

```
mkdir ~/bin
echo 'PATH+=:$HOME/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
mv "/path/to/spotlyrics.sh" ~/bin/spotlyrics && chmod +x ~/bin/spotlyrics
```

Then restart the shell (log out and back in) and you won't need the alias.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the shell scripts are not executable by just calling it's name, they should be run using "[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command))" command(in case of not c-shell, [dot command(.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)) can also be used).So while adding an alias in .bashrc or .bash_profile for running a shell script append source command before the path to the shell script.
In your case probably this should work:`

```
alias spotlyrics='source /Users/username/Documents/bash/spotlyrics.sh'`
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work. Because it worked for me.

Comment: This won't work in a shell because it is using curly quotes instead of ASCII quotes. Also, this isn't really any different than the original question's attempt - it uses `source` instead of executing the script, but it's still just an alias calling a script...

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out..I just copied it from question while answering. It should be single or double straight quotes( " , ' ). And it's an alias executing the script. In the question the user just pointed towards the script but wasn't executing it.using source executes it.